I can't connect to appwrite
Impossible to connect to appwrite. This is the error :
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to construct 'URL': Invalid URL
    at Account.<anonymous> (appwrite.js?v=d683b3eb:932:19)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at appwrite.js?v=d683b3eb:503:67
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at __awaiter (appwrite.js?v=d683b3eb:485:10)
    at Account.create (appwrite.js?v=d683b3eb:908:12)
    at createUserAccount (api.ts:8:36)
    at onSubmit (SignUpForm.tsx:42:27)
    at chunk-XTNSOE4L.js?v=d683b3eb:1629:15

I were try to use appwrite

Can you please provide the code that leads to this error? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

If anyone getting this error, There are some things you should do in order to solve this error
the issue likely lies in how Next.js handles environment variables. Here's a revised approach to address this:

Define Environment Variables:

Create a file named .env.local in your project's root directory (not tracked in version control).
Inside .env.local, define your Appwrite endpoint and project ID:
`APPWRITE_ENDPOINT=https://cloud.appwrite.io/v1

APPWRITE_PROJECT=663feb9e0027da7135b2`


Load Environment Variables (Next.js 12 and above):

Next.js 12 and above have a built-in way to access environment variables. Create a file named next.config.js (if it doesn't exist) in your project's root directory.
Add the following code to next.config.js:
`JavaScript
module.exports = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  env: {
    APPWRITE_ENDPOINT: process.env.APPWRITE_ENDPOINT,
    APPWRITE_PROJECT: process.env.APPWRITE_PROJECT,
  },
};`

This code exposes the environment variables from .env.local to your application under process.env.

Use Environment Variables in Appwrite Code:

Modify your existing appwrite.ts file to use environment variables:
TypeScript
import { Client, Account } from 'appwrite';

export const client = new Client();

`client
  .setEndpoint(process.env.APPWRITE_ENDPOINT)
  .setProject(process.env.APPWRITE_PROJECT);

export const account = new Account(client);
export { ID } from 'appwrite';`


Server-Side Usage (Optional):

If you're using Appwrite on the server-side (e.g., in API routes), this approach works seamlessly.
5. Client-Side Usage (Next.js 12 and above):
If you need Appwrite on the client-side (browser), you can still use environment variables with Next.js 12 and above:
Prefix the environment variables in .env.local with NEXT_PUBLIC_:
`NEXT_PUBLIC_APPWRITE_ENDPOINT=https://cloud.appwrite.io/v1
NEXT_PUBLIC_APPWRITE_PROJECT=663feb9e0027da7135b2`

Access them in appwrite.ts using
`process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_APPWRITE_ENDPOINT
 process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_APPWRITE_PROJECT.`

while using env variables convert it to String.Here is some example-
client
.setEndpoint(String(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_APPWRITE_ENDPOINT))
.setProject(String(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_APPWRITE_PROJECT_ID))

With these adjustments, your code should work with environment variables, allowing for easier configuration without directly including sensitive information in your code.
